# Wait time on server replies is sometimes very long when running the query over and over

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2017, standard-edition

As seen in this screen shot, I'm running the same query over and over again, comes back with 0 rows (as expected). For some reason I'm seeing very large wait times on server replies while running this on the server itself. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction as to why this might be occurring.

My guess is that its lack of resources or too many other things occurring but wondering how I can prove that.

MSSql server 2017 standard edition
64 core machine, 240 GB of ram

EDIT: output of wait stat added. 42 rows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you considered looking at wait stats?

Comment: Hi @ErikDarling I edited the post to include a screen shot of that select * from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks, is that what you were talking about?

Comment: The relevant wait data is in the session wait stats for the session running the query. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments on the main post above was super helpful. It lead me to find that I was getting millions of `CMEMTHREAD` waits and that this was in fact not normal.

```
select distinct wait_type, sum(waiting_tasks_count), avg(wait_time_ms) 
from  sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats
group by wait_type
order by 2 desc
```

The above showed me the huge wait times on the temp table for resources, this lead me to an [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4578496-fix-slow-performance-occurs-as-cmemthread-waits-occur-due-to-temporary-table-cachestore-memory-object-contention-in-sql-server-2016-and-2017-91a27a99-eee2-2be5-2e02-73b3be598490) mentioning that this issue is fixed in Cumulative Update 16 in SQL server 2017.

I ran `select @@version` and saw that I was running a RTM-GDR version of 2017 (unlike my other servers) and that only takes high priority security updates, not CU changes which I seem to need.